# how to parse json of 2D list in flutter

Tags: json, parsing, flutter, dart

i want parse this json

```
'supperset':[
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [1,8,9]
 ]
```

i use of this code when fetch data from server for parse it

```
class Session {

final List<List<int>> supersets;
Session._({ this.supersets});
factory Session.fromJson(Map jsonMap) {

 return new Session._(

  supersets : (jsonMap['superSets'].cast<List<int>>()),

);
}
}
```

but when user from this code get this errror

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast
```

how to parse it is correct this way but what get this error

Answer (score 1):

`List.from()` is useful when handling lists decoded from JSON that have identical member types.

Combine `map` with `List.from` to convert your `List<dynamic>` to a `List<List<int>>` which is probably what you'd like to end up with.

```
void main() {
  var jsonMap = json.decode('{"superset":[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,8,9]]}');

  // jsonMap['superset'] is a List<dynamic>, so lets 'map' it to a List<List<int>>
  // by mapping each of the top level elements to a List<int>
  // each 'l' is also a List<dynamic>, so convert that to a List<int> using .from
  var listOfLists =
      jsonMap['superset'].map<List<int>>((l) => List<int>.from(l)).toList();

  print(listOfLists); // expect [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 8, 9]]
  print(listOfLists.runtimeType); // expect List<List<int>>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

`type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast`

This error happen because you are casting a list of integers, but **YOU** know it is a list of intergers and not a list of string. Dart doesn't know what type of list the json is going to retrieve.

Therefore you must expect a `List<dynamic>`, it means the list can be of any variable. And then you use it as integers.

**Problem 2**

You have a misstype.

`supersets : (jsonMap['superSets'].cast<List<int>>()),`

should be

`supersets : (jsonMap['supperset'].cast<List<int>>()),`

**The final script should be:**

```
class Session {
  final List<List<dynamic>> supersets;
  Session._({this.supersets});
  factory Session.fromJson(Map jsonMap) {
    return new Session._(
      supersets: (jsonMap['supperset'].cast<List<dynamic>>()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't addressed how to convert it to a `List<int>` in case the OP needs it typed that way, e.g. for an API call - or just wants strong typing to assist the IDE in later lines.